# How to perform a database insert from a PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I'm having an issue with MySQL and PHP.

When I try to create a user from PHP and add to the database I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user', 'password') VALUES(, )' at line 1

This is my PHP code:

```
$user = $_REQUEST["user"];
$password = $_REQUEST["pass"];

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

// Insert a row of information into the table "example"
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts('user', 'password')
VALUES($user, $password)") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Data Inserted!";
```

Comment: Always filter data when you gonna use in database query. See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You should be using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` and your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. And finally, you really **should not** store passwords plaintext. I cannot stress that too much.

Comment: Data is not being inserted now, Why?

Comment: i managed to get this fixxed, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the field names with back-ticks (or nothing), not single-quotes, and presumably enclose the username and password in single-quotes.:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts(`user`, `password`)
VALUES('$user', '$password')") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, $user and $pass are both empty. Try using echo statements to verify those.

Answer (score 0):

Your values need to be enclosed.  I would use this as a query to insert the values.  Hope it helps.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts(user, password) VALUES('$user', '$password')")
```

Comment: this seemed to work, but no data is being added to the Database

Comment: Try checking your variables to see what you are actually trying to insert.  You can use print_r($_REQUEST).  Also be careful of using these variables directly in database query statements like you are. Make sure you sanitize the data and/or use a PHP Data Object (PDO) to prepare the statement.

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote values

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts('user', 'password') VALUES('$user', '$password')");
```

also you are not getting data, (use near ''user', 'password') VALUES(, ))

```
$user     = $_REQUEST["user"];
$password = $_REQUEST["pass"];
```